# Huawei Nexus 6p Product Id from fastboot mode

Tags: boot-loop, fastboot, nexus-6p

I want to unlock the bootloader of my Nexus 6P but I'm unable to retrieve my product ID from common way

```
*#*#1357946#*#*
```

Because my phone is stuck in boot loop.

Product ID is required by Huawei website to provide the unlocking code for bootloader.

I want to know where the product ID is stored in the android and is it possible to read it by using the fastboot commands?

**Update:** I have managed to raise a request for the bootloader unlocking key with Huawei support. I will update again, once I get the key.

**Update2:** I got the bootloader unlocking key from Huawei. However it does not seem to work or I am using the wrong command. Here are the commands that I have tried:

```
fastboot.exe flashing unlock VP2T97EWDWSZDX8U


fastboot.exe oem frp-unlock VP2T97EWDWSZDX8U
```

Both of them end up in an error with no specific description.

Comment: The thing is, N6P is ultimately a Nexus device and doesn't follow standard unlocking procedures of other Huawei phones. If you didn't turn on OEM unlocking in Settings before you had the bootloop, you're pretty much out of luck.

Comment: @AndyYan I think you are right. Although i have managed to raise a request with Huawei to get the bootloader unlock key. Hopefully that works!

Comment: There's no key needed in the first place. Provided you have the option turned on all you need is to execute `fastboot flashing unlock`; but without that option enabled, even with the key (other Huawei phones need it) you won't be able to break through, as `fastboot` will simply throw an error.

Comment: @AndyYan, I hadn't turned on OEM unlocking. The key is my only hope. Why wouldn't the key unlock the bootloader?

Comment: Starting Android 5.x, unlocking *will* require explicit user consent inside the OS (e.g. past the secure lockscreen), likely in an effort to stop thieves from unlocking BL straight-up, wiping the phone and then taking full fontrol.

Comment: I see. Well they should have an override if the actual customer contacts them with the bill of the phone! Such a shame! BTW, I am still waiting for a reply from them

Comment: Bootloader unlock is not covered by warranty, makes no sense that a manufacturer would provide any support for it.

Comment: @AndyYan, could you check the update2 in the question please?

Comment: As I said, Nexus phones are not meant to be unlocked this way - their protocol aren't supposed to "understand" the unlock codes.